# React Calendar with Touch Events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on a revamp of a legacy codebase over to react that utilizes jQuery based calendars on web and mobile (webview) portals and works fine at the moment.

Since we need to revamp everything to react, the problem i am facing is that as far as i have researched, there aren't any react based calendars that support touch events and safari which would be an issue since we would be using the same calendar in a webview in our mobile app.

Are there any react calendars that support touch events too? If not what could be the course of action in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

The [KendoReact Calendar](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dateinputs/calendar/) is working on touch devices.

> `import { Calendar } from '@progress/kendo-react-dateinputs';`

```
<Calendar />
```